# How to diagnose hung on shutdown

Tags: linux, linux-mint, shutdown

I've had some weird behavior on my System recently, being stuck at "*Reached target Shutdown*" but not shutting off because of a hung task, usually *kworker*, but only sometimes, at other times it will shut down fine. After a while it will show that a kworker process is still running

How can I diagnose hung on shutdown?

I am running Linux Mint 18.2 on a i5 with 16 GB RAM and two nvidia cards, a GTX 580 and a GT 620

Comment: If you don't receive much in the way of help here it is because you have leaped to a faulty conclusion, supported that faulty conclusion with erroneous reasoning based upon listing a directory, and then asked how to fix something that is not actually the case in the first place. A better question would stop after the first paragraph and ask _how to diagnose_ the shutdown problem, rather than leaping to a faulty conclusion about it. [Put down the chocolate-covered banana and step away from the European currency systems.](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html) (-:

Comment: Thank you for your input and hinting me in the right direction. Maybe those are two separate, unrelated problems indeed. However they appear to come up together. Could be expectation bias though. I will refine/split the questions later when I have a little more time on my hands.